# How to define a custom query string format for certain parameter types in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I defined a controller method with this signature:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChartsPage(
        string pageName, 
        DateTimeOffset sampleFrom,
        DateTimeOffset sampleTo)
```

That returns my page ViewModel after extracting some data in a certain time range.

In another page view, I created a link to the page that shows `ChartsPage` controller method output:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
   "ChartsPage",
   "Pages",
   new
   {
       pageName = "Overview",
       sampleFrom = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(-1),
       sampleTo = DateTimeOffset.Now
   })
```

The resulting url when I press the link is:

```
.../Pages/ChartsPage?pageName=Overview&sampleFrom=11%2F10%2F2017%2009%3A38%3A16%20%2B01%3A00&sampleTo=11%2F10%2F2017%2010%3A38%3A16%20%2B01%3A00
```

I'd like to format `DateTimeOffset` in the Url bar in a more readable way, by defining a custom serializer and deserializer for the parameters of type `DateTimeOffset`.

Example result (pseudo format):

```
.../Pages/ChartsPage?pageName=Overview&sampleFrom=20171110-1047Z0100&sampleTo=20171110-1147Z0100
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In the `ActionLink()` method, you can use `.ToString()` to format the values, for example `.ToString(yyyyMMdd.....)`. To bind it in the controller method, you would need to create a custom `ModelBinder` that reads the query string values and converts then back into `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. Is there a way to make it the standard for the whole website?

Comment: For binding, you can create a custom model binder for typeof `DateTimeOffset` and register in globally (so that every query string value that binds to a parameter that is typeof `DateTimeOffset` will use that ModelBinder`). For the link generation, if you did not want to use the `.ToString()`, you could create your own extension method to automatically format the values